# Alamofire 3: cancel request with custom error

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, alamofire

(Using iOS 9, Swift 2, Alamofire 3)

My app interacts with a REST service that requires a session token in the header. If the session token isn't already available before manager.request() is called, there's no reason to send the request only to have it fail. So I'd like to abort the request with my *own* error, and have the request's chained response handler take care of it - i.e. the caller wouldn't know that the request was actually never sent to the server.

What's the best way to do this with Alamofire 3?

Any way to have the same effect as Request.cancel() but with custom error, as below?:

```
static func request(method: Alamofire.Method, _ URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil) -> Request {
    let api = apiManager.sharedInstance
    guard let sessionToken = api.sessionToken else {
        let req = api.alamofireManager.request(method, URLString, parameters)
        req.cancel() // ***I'd like to do: req.cancelWithError(.NoSessionToken)
        return req
    }
    // Create request and add session token to header
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wrap Alamofire calls by your own methods. That's the best advice.